# How to send folders in c# through TCP?

Tags: c#, file, directory, transfer

I'm having trouble looking for a way to send whole folders over TCP. My initial idea was that the sender sends a string that contains the path of a given file like C://MyFolder/MySubFolder/MyFile then the receiver creates the folders and subfolders. The sender then goes ahead with the sending of the files containing their directory.

I think it goes without saying that this is not the best method in doing this. Is there a better approach?

EDIT:

Sorry if I was a little vague. I have a file transfer app that sends sends/receives files obviously and I want to add a way to send whole folders.

Comment: "Is there a better approach?" - FTP?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat, Yeah, sadly it has to be TCP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use famous archiving methods (zip, rar...) and transfer data. The extract the at the peer side. This way you save:

1. Implementing an error-prone
   recursive pattern.
2. Your bandwidth

Comment: Yes, I used DotNetZip and archived the whole folder, then extracted it at the receiver, then deleted the zip file. Works perfectly and exactly as it should BUT sadly it was rejected. I cant archive the files

Comment: Why it was rejected? Is it a homework and rejected by your teacher or you there's a technical issue? Anyway, if you gonna implement it yourself you should write a recursive function that iterates folders, send their names (you need some simple protocol of your own) and files inside.

Comment: Yeah a technical problem. If I were to send a folder with a 5gb file inside it, it would take a lot of time and resources to archive. I'm actually doing what you're saying right now but it's kinda hard because the receiver app already has a protocol (a poor one) for files. I'm thinking of redoing the receiving app.

Comment: So you have limited options with a legacy code. Use the protocol for file/folder names. Start from root folder, transfer the name (peer would create the folder) and then transfer the files inside. Then goto the next level and recursively do the same (it's not as easy as I'm saying!). I recommend kind of hashing for making sure the file is transmitted without corruption (i.e. MD5). You should take care of any UNWANTED situation like network problems... lots of work to do

Comment: Yes it was really not easy. It was for a company as part of our practicum. What I did was I sent the folder structure first, then the receiver creates that and files are transfered after. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need some sort of a file transfer protocol for that (i.e. FTP). Use an easy to setup c# FTP server library (i.e. this one: http://sourceforge.net/projects/csftpserver/) on the sending side and use `FtpWebRequest` on the client side to get the whole folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at existing protocols for this purpose? It seems you want to clone [FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol), maybe with a streaming mechanism like [tar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28file_format%29) in between.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider zipping/compressing:
You could have a look at GZipStream class for that.

http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial190_Zipping-files-using-GZipStream.html